# Failed to get request token. Authorization completed with an error. Twitter API with flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, api, flutter, android-studio, twitter

We are a project group trying to create a Twitter login page with flutter. We connect the project with firebase and in the first time it worked, but when I tried to run it with the same steps on my device I get an error. Is it because we use the same token or firebase account for different files? or I miss something?
I did add the callback URLs, sdk and firebase

> twittersdk://
>
> https://saanaad-dd***.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

**This is the code:**

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:twitter_kit/twitter_kit.dart';
import 'package:flutter_twitter_login/flutter_twitter_login.dart' ;
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _fbApp = Firebase.initializeApp();
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          // This is the theme of your application.
          //
          // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
          // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
          // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
          // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
          // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
          // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
          // is not restarted.
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: FutureBuilder(
          future: _fbApp,
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasError){
              print('Have error!');
            }//first if
            else if(snapshot.hasData){
              return MyHomePage(title: 'Sanad Flutter!');
            }
            else{
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }


          },//builder
        )

      //(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),




    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    DatabaseReference _testRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("test");
    _testRef.set("Hello World ${Random().nextInt(100)}");
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Future<auth.User> loginWithTwitter() async {
    var twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
      consumerKey: '********',
      consumerSecret: '***********',
    );
    final auth.FirebaseAuth _auth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
    //print('result unfound');
    final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();

    switch (result.status) {
      case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        var session=result.session;
        final auth.AuthCredential credential= TwitterAuthProvider.credential(accessToken: session.token, secret: session.secret);
        print('Entered case 1');
        print('session key');
        print(session.token);
        print(session.secret);

        auth.User firebaseUser=(await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print('Entered case 2');
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
        String newMessage = 'Login error: ${result.errorMessage}';
        print(newMessage);
        print('Error: in case 3');
        break;
    }
    return null;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: loginWithTwitter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**This is the error message with my prints:**

```
> I/TetheringManager( 8919): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.sanad
E/Twitter ( 8919): Failed to get request token
E/Twitter ( 8919): Authorization completed with an error
E/Twitter ( 8919): com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:94)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:191)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onFailure(Callback.java:48)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$2.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:79)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/Twitter ( 8919):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/flutter ( 8919): Login error: Failed to get request token
I/flutter ( 8919): Error: in case 3
```

**Note:** I used the same flutter default app and use the '+' button as a login-button temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

- i tried without firebase , it worked me ,
- so i think you can create app on twitter developer and just use key and scret key then in this "flutter_twitter_login: ^1.1.0" package add in twitter account add callback " twittersdk:// " is enough ,
- dont forget to put 
  in your androidManifest.xml ,
- and use the pub dev package "flutter_twitter_login: ^1.1.0" i think this might work ... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG1px.png)